# Adding result values from two different arrays together

Tags: javascript, math

Please take a look at my sample **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/tJfW9/embedded/result/)**

I have a running total for credits selected for Transfer. As you select the number of credits, the running total adds up. It's designed to stop at 6 credits per section. This part works fine.

What I'm trying to do is add two different result sets together...

**Communications** + **Humanities** = **Total Credits**

...and have it display in the **Total Credits:** field. This is where I'm getting lost.

**What I can't figure out is how to add two different fields together...**

This is what I'm using to get that final result... (*the 72 is so that the count will stop at 72 transfer credits maximum*)

**JavaScript...**

```
$(function($) {
    $('#total_Credits select').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#total_Credits select').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseFloat(elm.value, 10);
        });

     $('#total_Credits').html(Math.min(sum,72).toFixed(2))
    });
});
```

**HTML...**

```
Total Credits: &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="total_Credits" style="color: red; font-weight:bold; font-size: 2em;"></span>
```

Comment: What are you stuck on? Getting the values? Adding them? Updating the total field?

Comment: I suppose you could say... getting the values (which I can display individually), adding them together and displaying them.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, have the decency to include a comment. I've displayed my work up to this point and I'm stuck. I'm not here to have my code written...just get some assistance.

Comment: I downvoted; as noted below, this code has a lot of problems. You'd do well to learn a bit more about accessing the DOM before you ask this question.

Comment: So downvoting is your best response. Why don't you teach me something. The code in the jsFiddle works. Just stuck on one last task. I don't expect you to fix my issues. I do, however, expect some professional guidance in the right direction. Telling me to go and read something isn't an answer.

Comment: Well, for example, if you don't know how to select the values, you could google "select text from span" and you might [find the answer](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginnersquestion-how-to-select-value-between-span-tags). I downvoted this question because it appears to show very little research, and I doubt it will be useful to others in the future. The beauty of SO is that anyone else can disagree and vote it up.

Comment: @Mathletics Thank you. I can respect your angle. In my defense, there are some things that I don't realize I need to ask for, such as your example. Now, I know.

Comment: Another downvote. I have never once downvoted someone without leaving some type of criticism. Is it that hard to follow a simple online decorum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a different function for each group of selects. Instead, you can just use

```
$(function($) {
    var sum = function($els, prop) {
        var s = 0;
        $els.each(function(idx, elm) {
            s += parseFloat(elm[prop], 10) || 0;
        });
        return s;
    };
    $('.select-wrapper select').change(function() {
        var $wrap = $(this).closest('.select-wrapper');
        $wrap.find('.sum').html(Math.min(sum($wrap.find('select'), 'value'),6).toFixed(2));
        $('.total-sum').html(Math.min(sum($('.sum'), 'innerHTML'),72).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tJfW9/7/)

Note I have modified a bit the html in order to make it work, and I have fixed problems like duplicate `id`s and nonsense `<br>`.

Comment: webfrogs - choose this one, it's better :)

Answer (score 2):

You've got multiple problems going on.

The first is that id's must be unique.  You cannot have multiple lists with the same id.  Change "Credits" to a class not an id.

Second, there is no #total_credits select.  So that change event will never happen.  You'll want to calculate and set the grand total whenever any of the Credits select change.  You can do it in your existing change functions.  To do that, get the values of each of the selects and add them up.

Added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tnk9m/1/

```
calcTotals = function() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $('.total').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text()) grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
    });
    $('#total_Credits').text(Math.min(grandTotal,72).toFixed(2));

};
$('#communication select').change(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#communication select').each(function (idx, elm) {
        sum += parseFloat($(elm).val(), 10);
    });

    $('#total_communication').html(Math.min(sum, 6).toFixed(2));
    calcTotals();
});
```

etc...

Comment: Ok. But, how would I change them? They're labels. `<label for="Credits">Credits</label>`

Comment: Yes, the labels have to match the ids, but the ids have to be unique.  Whatever scheme you want to come up with is up to you.  In my fiddle, I just numbered them.

Comment: Updated because I noticed you are limiting the totals and getting the list box values wouldn't take that limit into account.