# Calling total from an array, multiply by a number and display a result

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

Please review this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/MBS9h/)**...

I have some select menus where if you select some college credit amounts, it computes a running total and displays it under the selects. (Thanks @barbara-laird)

I'm trying to take the total and multiply it by a number (561) and then display a result. The result is set not to exceed 40,392.

**This is the JS to calc the value I'm looking for...**

```
$('#total_Credits select').change(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#total_Credits select').each(function (idx, elm) {
        sum += parseFloat(elm.value, 10) * 561;
    });

    $('#total_money').html(Math.min(sum, 40392).toFixed(2))
    calcTotals();
});
```

...but it's not calculating the value. It's pulling from a valid ID.

I'm not sure why, but it's not displaying anything.

Comment: There are no `select` elements inside the `#total_Credits` span.

Comment: As pointed out in the [answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19847036/7469), there is no `#total_Credits select` so this code __never runs__.

Comment: But there is a total_Credits... It's here - `Transfer Credits:  &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="total_Credits"></span>` I did take your advice and I read up on some things... I always appreciate criticism.

Comment: `$('#total_Credits select').change` statement says look for a `select` element with a parent with id `total_Credits`, then when the `SELECT` element changes do this function. That is the issue. There isn't a select element to trigger the change event. What exactly are you trying to do? If it is to make a calc when the html changes then you need to do the calc at the time of the change not attempt to capture some event. It doesn't work that way

Comment: As an aside, `parseFloat()` only takes one argument.

Comment: @nnnnnn Should that be `parseInt()` then?

Comment: @webfrogs do you want decimal value or just the integer part? It doesn't really matter if you pass more than it needs as it will just ignore the extra params passed...

Comment: I need the decimal value. It's supposed to display a dollar amount.

Comment: @scrappedcola To answer your other question, I'm trying to take the total amount of transfer credits and multiply it by the amount 561, and have that product display.